# Specifics of List Membership

Tags: python, list

How does Python (2.6.4, specifically) determine list membership in general?  I've run some tests to see what it does:

```
def main():
    obj = fancy_obj(arg='C:\\')
    needle = (50, obj)
    haystack = [(50, fancy_obj(arg='C:\\')), (1, obj,), needle]

    print (1, fancy_obj(arg='C:\\'),) in haystack
    print needle in haystack

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which yields:

```
False
True
```

This tells me that Python is probably checking the object references, which makes sense.  Is there something more definitive I can look at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [(An Unofficial) Python Reference Wiki](http://pyref.infogami.com/in):

For the list and tuple types, `x in y` is true if and only if there exists an index i such that `x == y[i]` is true.

So in your example, if the `fancy_obj` class stored the value of `arg` in an instance variable and were to implement an `__eq__` method that returned True if the two `fancy_objs` being compared had the same value for `arg` then `(1, fancy_obj(arg='C:\\'),) in haystack` would be True.

The relevant page of the Standard Library reference is: [Built-in Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html), specifically [5.6 Sequence Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange)

Answer (score 4):

Here is code from the Python SVN:

```
static int
list_contains(PyListObject *a, PyObject *el)
{
    Py_ssize_t i;
    int cmp;

    for (i = 0, cmp = 0 ; cmp == 0 && i < Py_SIZE(a); ++i)
        cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(el, PyList_GET_ITEM(a, i),
                                           Py_EQ);
    return cmp;
}
```

so basically it uses the `==` with the object and each object in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Python is using the (equivalent of) the `==` operator.  If the `fancy_obj` class does not define `__eq__` (or the crufty old `__cmp__`, still supported for backwards compatibility) then equality, `==`, "falls back" to identity, `is`, and that appears to be what's happening here.

The relevant docs are [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange), and I quote:

`x in s`    True if an item of s is equal to x, else False

and "equal to" means `==` is true.